# Ruby Trying to access module variables within cousin class

Tags: ruby, variables, reference, module

In a script like this, how can I reference x from Klass?

```
module FatherofKlass

  module Uncle
   x = "my variable's string"
  end

  module Aunt
  end

  class Klass
   puts x
  end

end
```

I'm not sure what combination of `::`,`@@`, etc I can use. Ideally I could use an `attr` function but nothing I've tried has worked except for using constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access `x` from outside of `Uncle`'s definition--not the way you've defined it.  That's OK, because with a small change, you can do it.

## Why doesn't it work that way?

### What happens when Uncle is defined

To understand why your code doesn't work, you need to know a little about variable scopes, and how Ruby loads code.  When Ruby loads the code containing your module definitions, it executes it line by line.  Let's see what happens when module `Uncle` is defined.

```
  module Uncle
```

Ruby defines the module `Uncle` and sets `self` to `Uncle`.  Also, and this is the important part, Ruby creates a new scope.  A scope is where local variables get stored.

```
   x = “my variable’s string”
```

Ruby defines the *local variable* `x` and sets it to `"my variable's string"`.  Since `x` is a local variable, it belongs to the current scope, the scope created by the `module Uncle` declaration.

```
  end
```

This is where everything goes wrong for your code.  The `end` at the end of the module declaration destroys the scope that contains variable `x`, making it impossible to get to `x`.

### What happens when Klass is defined.

```
  class Klass
```

The class `Klass` is created and `self` is set to `Klass`.  Then a new scope is created.

```
   puts x
```

We try to access variable `x` *within the current scope*.  Since this scope belongs to the definition of `Klass`, it can only access local variables defined within that definition.  It can't reach into `Uncle`'s scope, and even if it could, that wouldn't matter: `Uncle`'s scope is long gone, and its `x` gone with it.

```
  end
```

## Fixing it with a constant.

If `x` doesn't need to change, then you can define it as a constant:

```
  module Uncle
    X = “my variable’s string”
  end

  class Klass
    puts Uncle::X
  end
```

By naming `X` in all-caps, Ruby creates a constant bound to module `Uncle`.  That constant can be referenced anywhere in `FatherofKlass` as `Uncle::X` (outside of `FatherofKlass`, you'd use `FatherofKlass::Uncle::X`).

By the way, your `puts` will execute *at the time Klass is defined*.  If you want it to be executed later, then put it inside a method:

```
class Klass
  define print_x
    puts Uncle::X
  end
end
```

Which would be invoked like this:

```
k = Klass.new
k.print_x
```

## Fixing it with a class instance variable.

If `x` needs to change, then making it a constant won't do.  Instead, you can make it a class instance variable:

```
module Uncle
  @x = 1
  class << self
    attr_accessor :x
  end
end

class Klass
  puts Uncle.x    # => 1
  Uncle.x = 2
  puts Uncle.x    # => 2
end
```

When Ruby defines a variable defined with `@`, it binds it to `self`.  Since `self` is `Foo`, it creates the class instance variable `@x`.  This class instance variable is bound to module `Uncle`, and so persists after Uncle is done being defined.

Don't be worried that we've defined a *class* instance variable bound to a *module*.  Classes and modules are closely related in Ruby.

Defining the accessor for `x` creates methods that allow `x` to be read and written.  Because accessors normally access *instance variables*, we need to nest it within `class << self` in order to define an accessor on a *class instance variable*.

Comment: Wow! thank you! The class instance variable lesson is just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
module FatherofKlass
  module Uncle
   X = "my variable's string"
  end

  module Aunt
  end

  class Klass
   puts FatherofKlass::Uncle::X
  end
end
# my variable's string
```